# Yii2: change class of div if select value is not promtp

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am building a quiz using Yii2. So by default promtp select is "--- Choose ---". I want to change if user select other option the div class will change from "notdone" to "done". But I cannot make it right.

My code:

```
$questions = app\models\Quizquestionuser::find()->where(['cate_id' => $id])->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->all();

foreach ($questions as $model24){
    
    echo "<div id='box' class='notdone'>";
    
    echo "<h4>" . $model24->title . "</h4>";

    $items2 = ArrayHelper::map(app\models\QuizAnswers::find()->where(['question_id' => $model24->id])->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->all(), 'id', 'answer');
    
    echo $form->field($model, 'user_answer[]')->dropDownList($items2, array('prompt'=>'--- Choose ---' ), ['style'=>'width:100px'])->label(false);
    
    echo "</div>";
}
```

And my JS:

```
$('select').change(function(){

var newabc  = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();

if(newabc = "--- choose ---"){
    $('#box').removeClass('done').addClass('notdone');
}else{
     $('#box').removeClass('notdone').addClass('done');
}
})

.change();
```

Updated working code:

```
<script>
        
        
    
$('select').change(function(){

var newabc  = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();

if(newabc === "--- choose ---"){
    $('#box').removeClass('done').addClass('notdone');
}else{
     $('#box').removeClass('notdone').addClass('done');
}
})

.change();
    
    </script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are assigning the value not comparing it.

You are using `if(newabc = "--- choose ---")`

When it should be `if(newabc === "--- choose ---")`

I think the code can be improved a bit in some other areas, so I will add a snippet, that way you can try it directly here.

```js
// Get the values directly from 'this' as a JQuery object.
$("select#s").change(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  const display = $('#result');
  const selectedOption = $this.find(":selected");
  const selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.val();
  const selectedOptionText = selectedOption.text();
  console.log(`Selected option value is ${selectedOptionValue}`);
  console.log(`Selected option text is ${selectedOptionText}`);

  // Then compare, I would use value instead, but you can use text.
  // if (selectedOptionText !== 'one')
  if (+selectedOptionValue !== 0) {
    $this.removeClass("not-done").addClass("done");
    display.html('Done');
    console.log("Select is done");
  } else {
    $this.removeClass("done").addClass("not-done");
    display.html('Not done');
    console.log("Select is not done");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">Not done</div>
<select name="my-select" id="s" class="not-done">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've marked your answer as solution but updated mine as well. Thank you again!